# How can I automate logging into a website?

Tags: internet, automation, browsing

I would like to automate login to some websites. I have servers working 365 days so I look for a good idea to reload the site opened at a particular frequency.

Any hints at how this can be done?

Comment: Couldn't you, you know, *rephrase* that question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Safari's "Top Sites" feature, they are periodically reloaded I believe (I have way too much recorded attendance on SO and no other explanation). Other browsers might have a similar feature, and Opera can automatically reload web pages.

Comment: The current version of Opera can automatically reload pages (right-click on the web page, then click on the "Reload Every" sub-menu).